# Custom module mysql4 model _beforeSave function throw error

Tags: magento-1.7, module, mysql

I am creating custom module  ,whose resource model is mysql4.In mysql4 file   i am trying to call _beforeSave but

```
it show error 
beforeSave() should be compatible with that of Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract::_beforeSave()
```

here config.xml and mysql4 file are Vendor.php

config xml....

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
        <modules>
            <Amit_Vendor>
                <version>0.1.1</version>
            </Amit_Vendor>
        </modules>
    <global>    
    <!-- define blocks -->
        <blocks>
            <vendor>
                <class>Amit_Vendor_Block</class>
            </vendor>
        </blocks>
    <!-- define helper -->
        <helpers>
            <vendor>
                <class>Amit_Vendor_Helper</class>
            </vendor>   
        </helpers>
         <models>
            <vendor>
                <class>Amit_Vendor_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>vendor_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </vendor>
            <vendor_mysql4>
                <class>Amit_Vendor_Model_Mysql4</class>
                    <entities>
                        <vendor>
                            <table>vendor_user</table>
                        </vendor>
                        <vendordetails>
                            <table>vendor_marchent_details</table>
                        </vendordetails>
                    </entities>
            </vendor_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
                <vendor_setup>
                    <setup>
                        <module>Amit_Vendor</module>
                    </setup>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_setup</use>
                    </connection>
                </vendor_setup>
                <vendor_write>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_write</use>
                    </connection>
                </vendor_write>
                <vendor_read>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_read</use>
                    </connection>
                </vendor_read>
            </resources>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <vendor>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Amit_Vendor</module>
                    <frontName>vendor</frontName>
                </args>
            </vendor>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <frontend>
    <events>
            <controller_action_layout_load_before>
             <observers>
                <vendor_is_logged_in_check>
                    <class>vendor/observer</class>
                    <method>addVendorlaycheck</method>
                </vendor_is_logged_in_check>
             </observers>
            </controller_action_layout_load_before>
        </events>
        <routers>
            <vendor>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                  <module>Amit_Vendor</module>
                  <frontName>vendor</frontName>
                </args>
            </vendor>
        </routers>
            <layout>
                <updates>
                    <vendor>
                        <file>vendor.xml</file>
                    </vendor>
                </updates>
            </layout>
    </frontend>

    <frontend>

    </frontend>
</config>


<?php
class Amit_Vendor_Model_Mysql4_Vendor extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {   
        $this->_init('vendor/vendor', 'vendor_id');
    }


    /**
     * Check customer by id
     *
     * @param int $customerId
     * @return bool
     */
    public function checkVendorId($vendorId)
    {
        $adapter = $this->_getReadAdapter();
        $bind    = array('vendor_id' => (int)$vendorId);
        $select  = $adapter->select()
            ->from($this->getTable('vendor/vendor'), 'vendor_id')
            ->where('vendor_id = :vendor_id')
            ->limit(1);

        $result = $adapter->fetchOne($select, $bind);
        if ($result) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    /* check vendor email id exits or not
    * if not exits then thrown exception
    */
    protected function _beforeSave(Varien_Object $vendor){

        parent::_beforeSave($vendor);
        if(!$vendor->getEmail()){
            throw Mage::Exception('Bluehorse_Vendor',Mage::helper('vendor')->__('Vendor email is required'));
        }
        if(!$vendor->getUserName()){
            throw Mage::Exception('Bluehorse_Vendor',Mage::helper('vendor')->__('Vendor User is required'));
        }
        $this->checkforBefore($vendor);
        $adapter=$this->_getWriteAdapter();
        $bind=array('email'=>$vendor->getEmail());
         $select = $adapter->select()
            ->from($this->getTable('vendor/vendor'), array('email'))
            ->where('email = :email');

            if ($vendor->getVendorId()) {
            $bind['vendor_id'] = (int)$vendor->getVendorId();
            $select->where('vendor_id != :vendor_id');
        }

        $result = $adapter->fetchOne($select, $bind);
        if ($result) {
            throw Mage::exception(
                'Bluehorse_Vendor', Mage::helper('vendor')->__('This Vendor email already exists'),
                Bluehorse_Vendor_Model_Vendor::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_EXISTS
            );
        }
         return $this;

    }
    protected function checkforBefore(Varien_Object $vendor){

        $adapter=$this->_getWriteAdapter();
        $bind=array('user_name'=>$vendor->getUserName());
         $select = $adapter->select()
            ->from($this->getTable('vendor/vendor'), array('user_name'))
            ->where('user_name = :user_name');

            if ($vendor->getVendorId()) {
            $bind['vendor_id'] = (int)$vendor->getVendorId();
            $select->where('vendor_id != :vendor_id');
        }

        $result = $adapter->fetchOne($select, $bind);
        if ($result) {
            throw Mage::exception(
                'Bluehorse_Vendor', Mage::helper('vendor')->__('This Vendor UserName already exists'),
                Bluehorse_Vendor_Model_Vendor::EXCEPTION_USERNAME_EXISTS
            );
        }
     return $this;
    }
    public function loadByEmail(Bluehorse_Vendor_Model_Vendor $vendor, $email){
        $adpter=$this->_getReadAdapter();
        $bind=array('email'=>$email);
        $select=$adpter->select()
        ->from($this->getTable('vendor/vendor'), array('vendor_id'))
         ->where('email = :email');
          $vendorId = $adpter->fetchOne($select, $bind);

        if ($vendorId) {
            $this->load($vendor,$vendorId);
        } else {
            $vendor->setData(array());
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

Please help me.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's happened because if you rewrite some method of parent class it should contain the same amount of entered parameters and parameters should be the same type.
In your case `_beforeSave` has one input parameter and its type is `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` but you use `Varien_Object`. PHP doesn't allow you to do that.
So instead of

```
protected function _beforeSave(Varien_Object $vendor)
```

Use

```
protected function _beforeSave(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $vendor)
```

Comment: Oleksii  now show error Declaration of Amit_Vendor_Model_Mysql4_Vendor::_beforeSave() should be compatible with that of Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract::_beforeSave()

Comment: Can you update the question with changed code?